# how to remove html comment tags using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to remove comment tags in an html file.

```
<!--- <script save and execute me> -->
```

must become:

```
<script save and execute me>
```

I tried

```
sed -i s_^<!-- \(.*\) -->$_\1_ text.sed
```

but that fails because the < and > are considered to be read in/out characters. I than tried:

```
sed -i 's_^<!-- \(.*\) -->$_\1_' text.sed
```

but than the \1 is not evaluated as it should. Hopefully somebody here has ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a file, test.html, containing:

```
<html>
<!--- <script save and execute me> -->
</html>
```

The command:

```
sed -e "s/<!---* *<\(.*\)> *-->/<\1>/" test.html
```

emits:

```
<html>
<script save and execute me>
</html>
```

Be aware that this would also transform:

```
<html>
<!-- some info explaining why we have commented out the following -->
<!-- <hr> -->
<!--- <script save and execute me> -->
</html>
```

into:

```
<html>
<!-- some info explaining why we have commented out the following -->
<hr>
<script save and execute me>
</html>
```

Comment: This (and every other attempt to parse HTML with sed) will fail spectacularly in so many different ways. I can count at least three different ways at a glance to make this fail. [Regex is not for parsing HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: The question wasn't about parsing HTML, it was about making a specific substitution in a file. The answer above isn't intended to do any more than solve the one specific problem. As far as it goes, SED is a fine tool for solving specific problems like this where the form of the input is clearly understood, regardless of the context.

Comment: Added additional example illustrating possible unintended consequences alluded to by @Darth Android.

Comment: @BillP3rd, thank you for your patience and your response to Darth Android. I'm more than aware that regex is not for parsing html but as you argued this is a very specific usecase for commenting out script references to local js files, and commenting in references to external js google api's